Elementary Divisors and Invariant Factors of $(\mathbb{Z}/360\mathbb{Z})^*$
Let $M = (\mathbb{Z}/360\mathbb{Z})^*$ as a $\mathbb Z$-Module.
The goal is to find the elementary divisors and invariant factors of $M_{tor}$.
I concluded that $M = M_{tor}$ since $k^{ord(k)} = \bar 1$ for every $k \in M$. (note that the module addition in $M$ is defined as multiplication in $\mathbb Z/360 \mathbb Z$).
with the euler function $\varphi(360) = 96$ i know that $|M| = 96 = 2^5 \cdot 3$.
But i can't  for the life of me figure out which "possible" combination of primes form the elementary divisors and invariant factors of this specific group. My best guess was that is must be either
$$M \simeq \mathbb Z_{12} \times \mathbb Z_{2} \times \mathbb Z_{2} \times \mathbb Z_{2}$$
or
$$M \simeq \mathbb Z_{12} \times \mathbb Z_{4} \times \mathbb Z_{2},$$
since $\bar 7$ is of order 12 which is the highest order in the group. But is that even a valid argument to make? I would appreciate if someone could show me the solution and maybe give some pointers on how to approach such problems.

By the CRT we have $M=U(360)\cong U(2^3)\times U(3^2)\times U(5)\cong (C_2 \times C_2) \times C_6\times C_4$ of order $4\cdot6\cdot 4=96$. So no cyclic group of order $12$.

thank you! i used the CRT on $C_6 = C_2 \times C_3$ again to get the Elementary Divisors $C_2 \times C_2 \times C_2 \times C_3 \times C_4$ which do correspond to a unique abelian group of order 96. and the corresponding invariant factors are $C_{12} \times C_2 \times C_2 \times C_2$ so at least i wasn't completely off :D

As noted in the first comment,  we have $C_2×C_2×C_4×C_6=C_2×C_2×C_2×C_3×C_4.$  This gives the elementary divisors.
This group can also be written as follows $C_2×C_2×C_2×C_{12},$ giving the invariant factors.
